# ReferenceError: greeter is not defined

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether, nodejs, hardhat

Here is the script in my `deploy.js`:

```
 const main = async () => {
 

  // We get the contract to deploy
  const Transactions = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Transactions");
  const transactions = await Transactions.deploy();

  await greeter.deployed();

  console.log("Greeter deployed to:", greeter.address);
}

const runMain = async() => {
  try {
    await main();
    Process.exit(0);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

runMain();
```

Here is the script in my `hardhat.config.js`:

```
// This is a sample Hardhat task. 
// https://eth-ropsten.alchemyapi.io/v2/Bn5tm9fX90ET1hKwb76lKJB0rzU3JBi2

require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");


module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.8.0',
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
      url: "https://eth-ropsten.alchemyapi.io/v2/Bn5tm9fX90ET1hKwb76lKJB0rzU3JBi2",
      accounts: ["63b598044c3cce8d656............b7c64beb17eb1687aebbefc5cac8a"]
    }
  }
}
```

This is my solidity contract script:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;

contract Transactions {
    uint256 transactionCount;

    event Transfer(
        address from,
        address reciever,
        uint256 amount,
        string message,
        uint256 timestamp,
        string keyword
    );

    struct TransferStruct {
        address sender;
        address reciever;
        uint256 amount;
        string message;
        uint256 timestamp;
        string keyword;
    }

    TransferStruct[] transactions;

    function addToBlockchain(
        address payable reciever,
        uint256 amount,
        string memory message,
        string memory keyword
    ) public {
        transactionCount += 1;
        transactions.push(
            TransferStruct(
                msg.sender,
                reciever,
                amount,
                message,
                block.timestamp,
                keyword
            )
        );

        emit Transfer(
            msg.sender,
            reciever,
            amount,
            message,
            block.timestamp,
            keyword
        );
    }

    function getAllTransactions()
        public
        view
        returns (TransferStruct[] memory)
    {
        return transactions;
    }

    function getTransactionCount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return transactionCount;
    }
}
```

And below is the error message I get anytime I try to compile it:

```
PS C:\Users\Temitope\Desktop\kredar\smart_contract> npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network ropsten
ReferenceError: greeter is not defined
at main (C:\Users\Temitope\Desktop\kredar\smart_contract\scripts\deploy.js:8:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at runMain (C:\Users\Temitope\Desktop\kredar\smart_contract\scripts\deploy.js:15:5)
```

Please kindly let me know what I'm doing wrong and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these lines in `deploy.js` and it should be fine

```
await greeter.deployed();
console.log("Greeter deployed to:", greeter.address
```

Comment: it's giving another error of...                                                                                                                            ReferenceError: Process is not defined
    at runMain (C:\Users\Temitope\Desktop\kredar\smart_contract\scripts\deploy.js:13:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Comment: Hi there, you should remove `Process.exit(0);` as well. Because you did not import Process and so the compiler does not recognize what is 'Process' and it got you this error